# Authentication with Oauth2.0 and Microsoft Entra ID

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

My problem is to find a way where I can successfully Login with the OAuth2.0 of Microsoft.

I have three php files. In the Index.php you will automatically move to the auth.php where you have to Login with Microsoft. The Autorization code will send to the success.php, where you get the Access Token. That is what I expect. I use Entra ID for it, so I replaced some things with 'XXXXXXXX'.

There is also a local Login, but thats not the Problem. The important thing is the authentication with Microsoft OAuth2.0 and Entra ID.

Index.php

```
<?php
//TODO: Azure Synchronisation 

session_start();


//* Überprüfen, ob der Benutzer authentifiziert ist
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) 
{
    header('Location: http://localhost/success.php');  //! Der Benutzer ist bereits authentifiziert
    exit();
}
else
{
header('Location: http://localhost/auth.php');  //! Der Benutzer ist bereits authentifiziert
exit();
}
     
//* Überprüfen, ob der Benutzer bereits mit einem Office-Dienst verbunden ist
if (isset($_SERVER['AUTH_USER'])) 
{
/*sleep(1);
header('Location: http://localhost/success.php'); //! Der Benutzer ist bereits angemeldet
exit();*/
}



require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Assets/Configs/server.php'); //*Einbinden von server.php
 

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        $username = $_POST['uid'];
        $password = $_POST['pwd'];

        //* Datenbankverbindung aufbauen
        $connectionInfo = array("UID" => $uid, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $databaseName, "CharacterSet" => $CharacterSet);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

        if ($conn) 
        {
            $enteredUsername = $_POST['uid'];
            $enteredPassword = $_POST['pwd'];
            $hashedEnteredPassword = hash('sha256', $enteredPassword); //!Passwort wird gehashed

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzername=?";
            $params = array($enteredUsername);
            $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC);
            $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);

            if ($stmt === false) 
            {
                die("<font color='red'><b>Abfragefehler:</b></font> " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }

            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($row) 
            {
                if ($hashedEnteredPassword == $row['HashedPasswort']) 
                {
                    
                    $_SESSION['user']=$row['Benutzername'];
                    $message = "<font color='green'><b>Sie wurden erfolgreich eingeloggt!</b></font>";
                    echo "Gehashtes Passwort aus der Datenbank: " . $row['HashedPasswort'];
                    header("Location: success.php");
                    exit();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $message = "<font color='black'><b>Ihr Benutzername oder Passwort ist falsch. Versuchen Sie es erneut</b></font>";
                }
            } 
            else 
            {
                $message = "<font color='black'><b>Ihr Benutzername oder Passwort ist falsch. Versuchen Sie es erneut</b></font>";
            }

            sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
            sqlsrv_close($conn);
        } 
        else 
        {
            die("<font color='red'><b>Verbindung fehlgeschlagen:</b></font> " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
?>

<head>
    <title>ITH - Development Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css.css">
    <script src="Js.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="Überschrift">
            <h1>ITH Bolting Technology - Login</h1>
        </div>
        <h4>Diese Seite dient zum Einloggen - This page is for Logging in</h4>
        <h4>Bitte geben Sie ihre Login-Daten ein - Please enter your Login-data</h4>
        <?php
            if(isset($message))
            {   
                echo $message; 
            }
        ?>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="Anmeldung">
                <form method="post" action="index.php">
                    <label for="uid"><b>Benutzername - Username</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Benutzername eingeben" name="uid" required>
                    
                    <label for="pwd"><b>Passwort - Password</b></label>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Passwort eingeben" name="pwd" required>
                    <button type="submit" value="Login">
                        Einloggen - Login
                    </button>
                  
                </form>
       
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

auth.php

```
<?php
session_start();

// Überprüfen, ob der Benutzer bereits authentifiziert ist
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    header('Location: http://localhost/success.php');
    exit();
}

// Include der erforderlichen Bibliotheken
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// Konfiguration für Azure AD OAuth2-Provider
$clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/success.php'; // Ändern Sie dies entsprechend Ihrer Konfiguration
$tenantId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/profile https://graph.microsoft.com/email https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access';



$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => $clientId,
    'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri'             => $redirectUri,
    'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => $scope, // Ändern Sie die Bereiche entsprechend Ihren Anforderungen
    'enablePkce' => true
]);


$authorizationUrl = $provider->getAuthorizationUrl();

$_SESSION['oauth2state'] = $provider->getState();

header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
exit();
?>
```

success.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="DE">

<?php
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['user'];
$Erfolg ="Sie haben sich erfolgreich angemeldet";

// Extrahiere den Autorisierungscode aus der URL
$authorization_code = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : null;
?>

    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Css2.css">
        <script src="Js.js"></script>
        <title>
            Erfolg
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="Überschrift">
                <h1>ITH Bolting Technology - Login</h1>
                <?php
                    echo "Benutzer: ";
                    echo($username);
                ?>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            <h3>

<?php

$Erfolg ="Sie haben sich erfolgreich angemeldet";

// Guzzle HTTP Client 
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/success.php'; // Ändern Sie dies entsprechend Ihrer Konfiguration
$tenantId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$scope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/profile https://graph.microsoft.com/email https://graph.microsoft.com/offline_access';

$provider = new \League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => $clientId,
    'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
    'redirectUri'             => $redirectUri,
    'urlAuthorize'            => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    'urlAccessToken'          => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token",
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => $scope // Ändern Sie die Bereiche entsprechend Ihren Anforderungen
]);

// Autorisierungscode aus der URL-Parameter erhalten
$authorizationCode = isset($_GET['code']) ? $_GET['code'] : null;

if (!$authorizationCode) {
    exit('Authorization code not provided.');
}

try {
    // Zugriffstoken anfordern
    $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('authorization_code', ['code' => $authorizationCode]);

    // Zugriffstoken erhalten
    $accessTokenValue = $accessToken->getToken();

    // Informationen über Benutzer abrufen
    $graph = new Microsoft\Graph\Graph();
    $graph->setAccessToken($accessTokenValue);
    $user = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me')
                  ->setReturnType(Microsoft\Graph\Model\User::class)
                  ->execute();

    // Benutzerinformationen anzeigen
    echo 'Benutzername: ' . $user->getDisplayName();
    echo 'E-Mail: ' . $user->getMail();

} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
    exit('Failed to get access token: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

// Überprüfen, ob die Anzahl der Benutzer in der Session vorhanden ist
    /*if (isset($_SESSION['user_count'])) {
        echo "<p>Anzahl der Benutzer aus Azure AD: " . $_SESSION['user_count'] . "</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Es wurden keine Benutzer abgerufen.</p>";
    }*/

?>

            </h3> 
            <div id="authCode">
                <?php
                    if ($authorization_code) 
                    {
                        
                         // Autorisierungscode auf der Seite anzeigen
                         echo "<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                            document.getElementById('authCode').textContent = 'Autorisierungscode: $authorization_code';
                        });</script>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div> 
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant code, not the entire code. This approach will help engage more people effectively.

Comment: _"The Autorizationcode will send to the success.php, where you get the Access Token. That is what I expect."_ - okay, and what is happening _instead_ ...?

Comment: Do you have output buffering enabled in your PHP configuration? If not, the attempt to pick up the session in success.php, after output has already been created, should fail.

Comment: At first forgot the index.php, because it is not unseful for my question. The fact is that you don't come to the success.php, because when you have to login with Microsoft, this Error code comes: AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption.

Comment: @Patrick did you configure the redirect URI as SPA in the Azure Portal?

Comment: @Rukmini yes it's configured as SPA

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"AADSTS9002325: Proof Key for Code Exchange is required for cross-origin authorization code redemption"*** usually occurs if the Azure Ad application is configured as SPA and you are making use of authorization code flow to authenticate.

Initially I got the **same error**:

[image]

**To resolve the error,** configure the redirect URL as WEB like below:

[image]

After updating the settings, I am able to successfully login like below:

[image]

Comment: Do you also get the Access Token to view the User information?

Comment: Yes  I got  Access Token to view the User information

Comment: I tried like you, but the Website don't work anymore. I delete the SPA from Azure AD and add the Web configure like you say. I don't know why it don't work

Comment: What is the error

Comment: I locked at Postman and I get the Access Token lol. Only the Website don't work.

Comment: Then it might be problem in the website

Comment: The Website :

localhost refused to connect.

Comment: Then there is some issue with the website not the Azure settings

Comment: I see, I will write you when I need your help. Thank you!

Comment: @Rukmini do you have any ideas, why I don't get the access token of the PHP-file and I only get the access token from postman?

Comment: I'll check your threads you posted for same. You can accept this solution if it solved the initial ask.

Comment: @Rukmini I try to view the Information of a User in the success.php. That's why I ask. Postman show me the AccessToken and the ID_Token, but every time I have to authentiicate, so I get every time a new autorizationcode, AccessToken and ID_Token

Comment: @Patrick did you resolve your issue